# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error nopcommerce

Tags: .net, iis, nopcommerce-4.2

I am getting this error in nopcommerce framework when I run published code on IIS or any server, The configuration is correct at my end and tried every possible solution. can anyone help me with it ?

Comment: You have to show the complete error page (and if possible your entire configuration file pointed out by the error page).

Comment: I found that nopCommerce is for Asp.Net Core shopping cart projects. In my search, I noticed that many users did not install the [.NET Core Run time](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) while hosting the nopCommerce project on the IIS. If you have also not installed that then you could try installing it may help to fix the issue. Ref: [Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - NopCommerce 4.0](https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/boards/topic/49399/error-50019-internal-server-error-nopcommerce-40)